# What happens if two pipes are redirected to a file at the same time

Tags: linux, bash, shell

If we have following commands:

```
# first
 cat /dev/random | base64 > test.txt &
```

```
# second
 cat /dev/random | base64 > test.txt &
```

if we run the first command and then run the second command, then stop them both (with `kill`) at same time,  where is `test.txt` come from? The first command or the second one, or both?

I have run following test; it seems like neither of the above? I don't know why.

```
$ cat /dev/random | base64 | tee 1.txt > test.txt &
$ cat /dev/random | base64 | tee 2.txt > test.txt &

# $ kill task1_id task2_id

$ ll -h
total 1.8G
drwxrwxrwx 1 user user 4.0K Dec  9 16:55 ./
drwxrwxrwx 1 user user 4.0K Dec  9 16:51 ../
-rwxrwxrwx 1 user user 627M Dec  9 16:55 1.txt*
-rwxrwxrwx 1 user user 585M Dec  9 16:55 2.txt*
-rwxrwxrwx 1 user user 627M Dec  9 16:55 test.txt*

$ md5sum *.txt
f83c833de426f22152e91f5c31bb0a7c  1.txt
e7535f298cc935c81064bfaf26dcd244  2.txt
35e7830de4decc1572b8b16d54170851  test.txt
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a mess. You won't get anything meaningful that way.

What happens is that first, one of the processes opens and truncates the file, then writes something to it. Its write pointer is left where it ended up at.

Then the second process opens and truncates the file (removing anything the first one wrote this far, but it doesn't matter), and writes something to it. Its write pointer is left where it ended up at.

Then, the processes write more, as much as they can, *at the positions where their respective write pointers are at that time*. But their order
depends on scheduling decisions by the OS, i.e. it's essentially random.
There's no guarantee they'll stay in sync, so they may partially overwrite each other at various points in time. The result is likely to be a mix of both data sets.

A short test with `yes`:

```
$ yes AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA > test.txt & \
  yes BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB > test.txt & \
  sleep .3; kill %1 %2
$ uniq -c test.txt
  14556 BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB
      1 BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
  76367 AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
      1 AAAAAAAABBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB
1033303 BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB
      1 AAAAA
1532199 AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
```

`uniq -c` counts lines repeating identically, so we can see that here, `B`s were printed for some 14556 lines worth, then `A`s for 76367 lines etc. `yes` should write blocks containing full lines, so the mixed-up lines should be due to the two processes overwriting each other.

Note that if you used appending redirections, `>> test.txt` instead, then all writes would go to the end of the file (at the time of the write, disregarding the individual write pointer positions), and there'd be no overwrites, you'd get all the data in, just interleaved (randomly).

Comment: Thanks for your clarify, I've been experiencing some weird lag on my cluster lately, this could be causing two pipe characters to be written to the same file, I can't checkout the output file, is there any setting that can make the file reject the second pipe data from being written?

Comment: @zhang other than creating the file with read-only permissions, probably not

Comment: Thanks, I will try other workground, Your answer is very detailed and clarify